# Can a android device start giving null value for device id?

Tags: android, null, device

I have an app on the market. When you start playing your device id is linked to your account so you don't have to log in manually. For some time now a few people had a problem. They started logging in into different accounts. What seems to be the problem is that some devices give a null value when asked for device id. With a few accounts with a null device id, people were logging into different accounts.

I read that some devices will do that. But it seems that there was no problem during account creation and then playing for a while.

I know this is not the best method and google discourages using device ids since they can change on fabric reset.

Can a device for some reason stop giving its id(besides the fabric reset)? 
Anyone know of a different way to identify the user with out him needing to put in a login or password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes some phones have bugs in them where they will return NULL for Android ID.  I think if you want to continue to use them you'll always need a way to tie that handset to an account, email, username.  That way if the Android ID is unrecognized they could login using their email or username, and password to associate them again.  You'll always have issues where someone buys a new phone and needs a way recover their account if you don't.

A better option is every Android phone is attached to a Google account.  And using the AccountManager class you can use those credentials to authenticate to your software automatically and the user doesn't have to enter username/password.  And you'e centralized their identity.  Also with this method you don't require the extra permissions to read data that has potential security issues too.

Comment: We have an option of recovering an account if someone sells the device or loses it.

Hmm I was thinking about the google accounts but I didn't do the research just yet on it. Other way is to generate an id on the server and then keep it in the app on the device. If a user uninstalls it or loses the device the account recovery option should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a random UUID after the user has installed your app.

Do not use hardware ids, because not every type of hardware is found in every type of Android device. Another reason not to use them is, if someone sells his phone, the user changes but the device id not! This has serious privacy and usability implications you do not want to have.

See the talk [Android Protips](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/android-protips-advanced-topics-for-expert-android-app-developers.html) (from google io 2011). Tune in at 15:00 to see more reasons and a detailed descriptions on how to use random UUIDs for your usecase.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Will have to think about what will be easier a UUID or trying to use the google account.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem In my case when first install the app it is giving null id . but after that it is giving me all three IMEI, ANDROID_ID and deviceID.

BTW, you can find the ways to identify the devices here

http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/cms/cnts/knowledge.detail.view.do?platformId=1&cntsId=9640

Comment: I read a similar text here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

Comment: also note that Random number can be the one solution. On installation time generate the random number (large enough) and store it in database.

Comment: and my problem get solved there is some bug in code. Android_id is the good one for identify the devices.

Answer (score 0):

Also some research prototypes try to prevent phones from collecting this information.